# Understanding "what fraction of" in a math problem

Tags: mathematics

I am faced with a very problematic wording of a math problem. I can infer what the author meant from the solution, though, I was wandering for the correct linguistic interpretation of the sentence.

> Damian needs 1/4 of the wood in the shed on the first day and 2/9 of
>   the remaining wood on the second day to make a tree-house in his
>   backyard. Given that 2/5 of the wood in the shed is unusable due to
>   fungal damage, what fraction of usable wood is left once he has
>   completed the tree-house?

Is that the fraction, (left usable wood)/(total usable wood) or (left usable wood)/(total wood)? does the fact that it is the fraction of 'something' implies that the whole must come from that something?

Comment: Working through a math problem on EL&U is like flipping on ESPN and watching poker.

Comment: Does the author suggest the answer they expect?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes. When looking at the authors' solution, it is obvious that they did mean (left usable wood)/(total usable wood).

Comment: That's what the English would strongly suggest (arguably demand), but I've come across situations where default interpretations don't lead to the required answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that since the question only asks for the amount of *usable* wood left, it wouldn't make sense to calculate "What fraction of the total wood" since 2/5 of the total wood cannot be used.

> Does the fact that it is the fraction of 'something' implies that the
>   whole must come from that something?

Answer - Yes.

Another example -

> A four-piece pizza has macaroni on two of its pieces. Calculate the
>   fraction of the pizza with macaroni.

So the fraction of *pizza* with macaroni must come from that whole piece of *pizza*.

Comment: Given how badly the question is phrased, is the assumption that the calculation must make sense logical?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Badly phrased? It's completely clear to me what the maths question is asking.

Comment: Are the four pieces of pizza the same size? (Sorry, couldn't resist maths *and* pizza.)

Comment: @Andy T I assume your answer would be 11/36, as that is what the default interpretation suggests, but after being in maths moderation meetings (I taught maths for over a decade), I'd guess that 11/35 ('the fraction of the wood one finds  in the shed in the final situation that is usable') is what the author expects.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, 11/36. Where on earth have you got 11/35 from? I'm trying to work out what other calculation could be possible from the given wording, and I have no clue what you've interpreted. And I'm normally quite good at finding ambiguity.

Comment: '... what fraction of usable wood is left?' could be taken as '... what fraction of the wood left is usable?' (which is the basis of the question). Hopefully, OP will give the 'answer'. Have you any experience of maths moderation? Pragmatics is sadly often involved ... hence the need to discuss answer schemes. I remember once the silliness of the use of 'flat' to mean 'horizontal' (as per buildingspeak but not mathspeak) in 'a flat roof' in an examination investigation.

Comment: To downvoters - Please explain your actions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Only just seen your comment. I can't understand how "what fraction of the wood left is usable" is a viable interpretation of "what fraction of usable wood is left". I have no experience of maths moderation, but I can understand the concept of avoiding ambiguity; and your flat roof is a great example. That said, this ELU website isn't about "what wrong interpretations could people make?" but "what does this phrase actually mean"; and there's only one answer to that for "fraction of usable wood", in my opinion.

Comment: @Andy T There's the problem that the omission of the indefinite article from  'what fraction of the usable wood is left' renders this arguably ungrammatical (certainly unidiomatic) and hence open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

"what fraction of usable wood" means "how much of the usable wood, expressed as a fraction".

It can only mean (left usable wood)/(total usable wood).